# sending SIP messages with C#

Tags: c#, sip

I am trying to send a predefined message to our SIP phones which will trigger an event(reboot) in C#. I found some scripts in other languages (perl/python) which do exactly what i am trying to do but have never done this before. I have most of if ported over but really don't know if i have all of right elements. Here is script i am trying to port:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Net::Ping;
use Socket;

my $phone_ip = $ARGV[0];
sub reboot_sip_phone {    # Send the phone a check-sync to reboot it

$local_ip = $phone_ip;
$sip_to   = $phone_ip;
$sip_from = "0";
$tm       = time();
$call_id  = $tm . "msgto$sip_to";
$httptime = `date -R`;
$MESG     = "NOTIFY sip:$sip_to\@$phone_ip:5060 SIP/2.0
             Via: SIP/2.0/UDP $local_ip
             From: <sip:$sip_from\@$local_ip>
             To: <sip:$sip_to\@$phone_ip>
             Event: check-sync
             Date: $httptime
             Call-ID: $call_id\@$local_ip
             CSeq: 1300 NOTIFY
             Contact: <sip:$sip_from\@$local_ip>
             Content-Length: 0 ";

$proto = getprotobyname('udp');
socket( SOCKET, PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, $proto );
$iaddr = inet_aton("$phone_ip");
$paddr = sockaddr_in( 5060, $iaddr );
bind( SOCKET, $paddr );
$port = 5060;

$hisiaddr = inet_aton($phone_ip);
$hispaddr = sockaddr_in( $port, $hisiaddr );

if ( send( SOCKET, $MESG, 0, $hispaddr ) ) {
    print "reboot of phone ", "$phone_ip", " was successful", "\n";
}
else { print "reboot of phone ", "$phone_ip", " failed", "\n"; }

}
exit;
```

this is my code so far:

```
class Driver
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(args[0]))
        {
            var phone_ip = args[0];
            SipMessage newMsg = new SipMessage(phone_ip);
            IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse(phone_ip);
            IPEndPoint end_point = new IPEndPoint(addr, 5060);
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(newMsg.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("sending message: " + newMsg.ToString());
            socket.SendTo(send_buffer, end_point);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent message to " + phone_ip);
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("Message did not send");
    }
}

class SipMessage
{
    private string _to, _from, _call_id, _msg;
    private DateTime _time;

    public SipMessage(string p_ip = "")
    {
        _to = p_ip;
        _from = "<sip:test>";
        _time = DateTime.Now;
        _call_id = _time.ToString() + "msgto" + _to;
        _msg = String.Format("NOTIFY sip:" + _to + ":5060 SIP/2.0" +
                            "\nVia: SIP/2.0/UDP " + _to +
                            "\nFrom: {0};tag=1530231855-106746376154 " +
                            "\nTo: <sip:{1}:5060> " +
                            "\nEvent: check-sync " +
                            "\nDate: {2} " +
                            "\nCall-ID: {3} " +
                            "\nCSeq: 1 NOTIFY " +
                            "\nContact: {0} " +
                            "\nContent-Length: 0 ", _from, _to, _time, _call_id);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
         return _msg;
    }
}
```

}

i have run the code and tested on a phone but it won't kick start the event. Am I on the right track? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you could use my C# sipsorcery nuget package.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using SIPSorcery.SIP;
using SIPSorcery.SIP.App;
using SIPSorcery.Sys;
using SIPSorcery.Sys.Net;

namespace SipSendNotify
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int _defaultSIPUdpPort = SIPConstants.DEFAULT_SIP_PORT;             // The default UDP SIP port.
        private static SIPTransport _sipTransport;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Configure the SIP transport layer.
                _sipTransport = new SIPTransport(SIPDNSManager.ResolveSIPService, new SIPTransactionEngine());

                // Use default options to set up a SIP channel.
                var localIP = LocalIPConfig.GetDefaultIPv4Address(); // Set this manually if needed.
                int port = FreePort.FindNextAvailableUDPPort(_defaultSIPUdpPort);
                var sipChannel = new SIPUDPChannel(new IPEndPoint(localIP, port));
                _sipTransport.AddSIPChannel(sipChannel);

                SIPCallDescriptor callDescriptor = new SIPCallDescriptor("test", null, "sip:500@67.222.131.147", "sip:you@somewhere.com", null, null, null, null, SIPCallDirection.Out, null, null, null);
                SIPNonInviteClientUserAgent notifyUac = new SIPNonInviteClientUserAgent(_sipTransport, null, callDescriptor, null, null, (monitorEvent) => { Console.WriteLine("Debug: " + monitorEvent.Message); });
                notifyUac.ResponseReceived += (resp) => { Console.WriteLine(resp.ToString()); };

                notifyUac.SendRequest(SIPMethodsEnum.NOTIFY);

                ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                mre.WaitOne();
            }
            catch (Exception excp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Main. " + excp);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While your API looks VERY intuitive, it doesn't exactly help clarify what elements are required or missing. I did download the package just to play around though ;). I haven't seen this anywhere, but does this custom message need to come from the UAS and/or Registrar in order for the UAC to accept the message?

Comment: NOTIFY requests are normally used as part of a SIP event dialog. The dialog gets set up by a SUBSCRIBE request. A NOTIFY request is normally used to inform a party that something has happened such as a new voicemail. In your case you sound like you want to send a NOTIFY to trigger an action on the phone. The mechanics of the SIP messages for your case will be specific to the phone manufacturer and not part of the SIP standard. You'll need to look into the manufacturer's documentation.

Comment: the issue is less about content of the message and more so about whether or not i my code is accurately representing the original Perl Implementation. I am not familiar with the Perl language, so i am not sure what functions like inet_aton(), socket_addr() return or do.

Comment: Get an IP address object and create a socket... http://perldoc.perl.org/Socket.html#%24ip_address-%3d-inet_aton-%24string